# Xcode 4 changing bundle identifier causes Xcode to hang at 'Attaching to'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, identifier

I have currently got a problem that is driving me crazy!

I have an iOS Xcode project and need to change the bundle identifier.
However when I change it in the info.plist it stops Xcode from attaching to the process in the simulator. It installs the app in the simulator just fine but it just hangs at "Attaching to (App Name)".

I have tried the obvious cleaning, deleting build / derived data folder but nothing seems to work.
If I change it back to the original identifier it starts working again.

I can reproduce this easily in a fresh project by simply creating a project, run (with original identifier), changing the identifier, clean etc and then run again.

If I change the identifier before running the fresh project everything is fine. But after the first build I get this problem. This seems to me like Xcode is caching something somewhere but I can't think what or where?

I am running Xcode 4.1 on Lion. We had some major issues with 4.2 so I am hesitant to upgrade.

Anyone ever come across this before?

Answer (score 9):

Also had this issues.
You normally can solve it by restarting your device / simulator and clean/build the app.

Solved?

Comment: Life saver! I must have forgotten the first rule of IT 'have you turned it off and on'! Its funny as I thought I had rebooted since finding this issue but I guess not. Thanks again

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you so much for this response, I had tried everything _except_ restarting the simulator.